# Debugging Illegal Address Error within CUDA kernel using NVIDIA's Nsight (Ubuntu)

Tags: debugging, cuda, nsight

My cudaPeekAtLastError() call after my kernel execution is catching an "Illegal address" error. My block and grid sizes are large enough that I'm overwhelmed by trying to find out which access is causing the error. How would you go about figuring it out in nsight?

Comment: Why is this thread closed? It would be beneficial to discuss general strategies in dealing with problems like this. CUDA kernel can be very complicated, I would not expect the posters to post their entire kernel code every time. It is just not possible!

Answer (score 1):

Under "Debug Configuration", CUDA-memcheck should be enabled.

Comment: Yes but this check almost never does anything. It did absolute nothing when the CUDA reported illegal address error on return from the kernel call.